# ESP32 based door/window sensor using a reed switch (logic issue)

Tags: esp8266, esp32, reed-switch

I have an ESP32-based reed sensor used to monitor door and window events. ESP32 is put into deep sleep mode, and the reed switch is connected to a RTC pin in order to wake up the MCU (external event wakeup). After waking up, the MCU transmits the data and again goes back to deep sleep, and this cycle goes on.

The problem arises when an event continues, i.e., when the window is not closed and remains open continuously. In this case, the ISR routine wakes up the MCU again and again until the door is closed; this is expensive on the battery. How can we optimise this by not allowing the ISR routine to trigger the MCU if the state remains the same?

Comment: What options you have for the interrupt sensitivity? Can you make it sensitive to falling or rising edge, or low or high level?

Comment: One Solution: We could add a flag in the RTC memory, and write the state of the previous event and ignore if the same event occurs. Is there a better solution than this, I would love to  have an hardware solution than software, something like an SR Latch which will be set by the reed and reset only when the door is closed. this way only one event will be triggered. I am pretty new to all of this, what could be an optimal solution to this remains elusive to my little brain.

Comment: @justme I could set to rising or falling edge, apologies i might be missing your point, how does that help with the trigger ? :(

Comment: If the window is open, change the interupt edge to detect the window close event?

Comment: @Suresh Many, if not most, MCUs include the ability to interrupt (and wake up) on ***both*** rising and falling edges. I don't know about the ESP32 case and don't want to spend time searching the issue. There is no reason to wake up continually in such cases, as only a "change" causes the MCU to wake up. You can separately read the I/O, once awake, to figure out the state (open or closed.) You do NOT necessarily need to maintain a separate internal state, since you can just look at the I/O, instead. But you may want to, just the same, for other unstated reasons. Which is fine.